# Why cant nullable arrays/hashmaps be accessed using []

Tags: syntax, kotlin

When I have a nullable array/list/hashmap such as

```
var x: ArrayList<String>? = null
```

I know can access the element at index 1 like so

```
var element = x?.get(1)
```

or I could do it in a unsafe way like this

```
var element = x!![1]
```

but why can't I do something like this

```
var element = x?[1]
```

what's the difference between getting elements from an array using the first example and the last example, and why is the last example not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you're using the safe call operator `?.` to call the `get` function with it.

In the second example, you're using the `[]` operator on the non-nullable return value of the `x!!` expression, which of course is allowed.

However, the language simply doesn't have a `?[]` operator, which would be the combination of the two. The other operators offered are also don't have null-safe variants: there's no `?+` or `?&&` or anything like that. This is just a design decision by the language creators. (The full list of available operators is [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html#operators-and-special-symbols)).

If you want to use operators, you need to call them on non-nullable expressions - only functions get the convenience of the safe call operator.

---

You could also define your own operator as an extension of the nullable type:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>?.get(index: Int) = this?.get(index)

val x: ArrayList<String>? = null

val second = x[2] // null
```

This would get you a neater syntax, but it hides the underlying null handling, and might confuse people who don't expect this custom extension on collections.

Comment: Thanks! Another thing i wanted to know was if I'm doing a x[1] would it compile at all differently from x.get(1) ?

Comment: You can use Ctrl+click or Ctrl+B on `[]` and you'll see that it jumps straight to the `get` function, so no, there is no difference between the two. (You can also check the bytecode, using the `Show Kotlin Bytecode` action)